# Dialog in Recyclerview - IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, view, dialog

I have a dialog which i set to play video in fullscreen on button click in recyclerview.So whenever i tap on fullscreen button on video player it crashed with `IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.`

I don't want to remove view from recyclerview cuz i when i add back same view it overlap items on recyclerview. So i created new Video player instance and give it to dialog's `addContentView` method but its give same error.

```
public class ExoPlayer_Main {

    public static final String TAG="###ExoPlayer###";
    MediaSource mediaSource;
    Context context;
    PlayerView playerView;
    SimpleExoPlayer player;
    boolean playWhenReady=false;
    long playbackPosition;
    int currentWindow;
    int newPlayerState=1;
    List<Uri> mediaList=new ArrayList<>();
    ComponentListener componentListener=new ComponentListener();
    private static final DefaultBandwidthMeter BANDWIDTH_METER = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
    private FrameLayout mFullScreenButton;
    //Fullscreen Setting
    ImageView mFullScreenIcon;
    private boolean mExoPlayerFullscreen = false;
    private Dialog mFullScreenDialog;




    public ExoPlayer_Main(Context context, PlayerView playerView) {
        this.context = context;
        this.playerView=playerView;

    }

    public void initializePlayer(Uri uri,int mediaType){
        Log.d(TAG,"Init Player Calling ");
        if (player==null){
            player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context);           
            player.clearVideoSurface();
            player.addListener(componentListener);
            player.setPlayWhenReady(playWhenReady);
            player.seekTo(currentWindow,playbackPosition);
            player.clearVideoSurface();
            mediaSource = buildMediaSourceNew(uri,mediaType);
            playerView.setPlayer(player);
            player.prepare(mediaSource);
            initFullscreenButton();
        }


    }






    private void initFullscreenButton() {


        PlayerControlView controlView = playerView.findViewById(R.id.exo_controller);
        mFullScreenIcon = controlView.findViewById(R.id.exo_fullscreen_icon);
        mFullScreenButton = controlView.findViewById(R.id.exo_fullscreen_button);
        mFullScreenButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!mExoPlayerFullscreen){
                    openFullscreenDialog();
                }else{
                    closeFullscreenDialog();
                }

            }
        });

    }
    private void openFullscreenDialog() {
        initFullscreenDialog();
        ((ViewGroup)playerView.getParent()).removeView(playerView);
        player.setPlayWhenReady(false);
        mFullScreenDialog.addContentView(playerView, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        mFullScreenIcon.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_fullscreen_skrink));
        mExoPlayerFullscreen = true;
        mFullScreenDialog.show();
    }


    private void closeFullscreenDialog() {

        ((ViewGroup) playerView.getParent()).removeView(playerView);
        FrameLayout playerAdd =  ((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.main_media_frame);
        playerAdd.addView(playerView);
        mExoPlayerFullscreen = false;
        mFullScreenDialog.dismiss();
        mFullScreenIcon.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_fullscreen_expand));
    }

    private void initFullscreenDialog() {

        mFullScreenDialog = new Dialog(context, android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen) {
            public void onBackPressed() {
                if (mExoPlayerFullscreen)
                    closeFullscreenDialog();
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        };
    }
```

I need to open fullscreen dialog with my video player and when i close video it won't mess my `recyclerview`

Answer (score -1):

I didn't find the issue on your code, but wouldn't it be better to create a fullscreen activity? You can create a fragment class to handle exoplayer, then you just need to inflate it on your fullscreen layout and on you recyclerview.
You just need to set extras with the actual position of the video when the user click on the recyclerview, don't forget to set a fullscreen style in the tag of your fullscreen activity on your Manifest file.

Comment: Yes but our requirement is Dialog whenever i try to open fullscreen dialog i get above exception

Comment: did you already tried remoe the view before initFullscreenDialog method?

Comment: if i remove view then on returning back to recylcerview it messed recycler view layout